# Why is axios returning "Promise { <state>: "pending" }"

Tags: promise, axios

```
var user = axios.post(url, { data }).then(res => {
    return res.data
})
```

I think the following code should return JSON data but instead it is returning "Promise { : "pending" }". Any help please

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to reinvent the weel. If you want to learn about `promises`, here is the MDN web doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

If you want a solution to your problem you can either :

```
axios.post(url, { data }).then(res => {
    var user = res.data
})
```

Or in an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) you can use the [await operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await):

```
var user = (await axios.post(url, { data })).data
```